# laravel query return question mark in second argument

Tags: laravel

Hello this my firs question here hopeful to find solution to my issue;

```
 $companyId=DB::table('users')->where('id',Auth::user()->id)
  ->Value('Co_id');
        $Companies=Company::where( 'Co_id' ,$companyId )->first();
       dd($Companies);
```

$companyId = it's return the result correct and work good.
$Companies= it's return "?" instead of the previous value, even if i replace variable with other number it still return "?"  if i remove the second argument it give me `Co_id` is null.

Comment: If you have a Relationship between `User` and `Company`, you should simply be able to do `auth()->user()->company`. Also, `DB::table('users')->where('id', auth()->user()->id)` is completely redundant, since `auth()->user()` would return the same thing as that whole query.

Comment: That code will dump either null or a `Company` object. It will never dump a string of any sort.

Comment: And do take the time to learn about relationships, as Tim Lewis says you will be saving yourself much work. Relationships are a fundamental part of Laravel – like one of the primary reasons it was created.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$companyId = DB::table('users')
  ->where('id',Auth::user()->id)
  ->first()
  ->Co_id;
$Companies = Company::where( 'Co_id' ,$companyId )->first();
dd($Companies);
```

Comment: it's seems it does not read the second argument in the query , I really don't know why, this is my first time to face this issue